# Replacing all negative values conditional on the attributes of the variable independent of type

Tags: r, replace, range, label, na

I have a very large mixed dataset (character variables, numerical variables, factors), in which negative values often represent missing values, see `Scales`, but not always, see `Profit` :

```
     Country Ccode  Year Profit Scale    ID Happiness_d Power_d  ID_d
  <chr>   <fcr> <dbl>     <dbl> <labelled>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 France  FR     2000      1000  NA        1      40000. 160000.  1.67
2 France  FR     2001     -1200   1        1      80000. 320000.  1.67
3 France  FR     2000      1400   0        2      40000. 160000.  1.67
4 France  FR     2001      1600   3        2      80000. 320000.  1.67
5 UK      UK     2000     -1000  -9        3      40000. 160000.  1.67
6 UK      UK     2001      1000   2        3      80000. 320000.  1.67
7 UK      UK     2000      1000   4        4      40000. 160000.  1.67
8 UK      UK     2001      1000   0        4      80000. 320000.  1.67
```

I wanted to replace all negative values with NA's using:

```
df[df< 0] <- NA
```

The issue is, although it is intended to remove negative values representing NA's such as in `Scale`, it would in the example dataset also remove negative numbers in `Profit`, which are obviously not NA.

As a result I would like to make the result conditional on the range of the variable. The structure the `Scale` variable is as follows:

```
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:135894] NA NA 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Do You Use Technology Licensed From A Foreign-Owned Company?"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%24.0g"
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:3] -9 1 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Don't Know (Spontaneous)" "Yes" "No"
> names(New_Comprehensive_June_25_2018$e6)
```

I have figured out that with the `haven` library [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjlabelled/vignettes/intro_sjlabelled.html) you can get out the factor levels from;

```
   ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:3] -9 1 2
```

with get_values().

```
get_values(df$Scale)
[1] -9 1 2
```

Would it be possible to have the solution only remove these negative factors instead of other negative values?

```
..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:3] -9 1 2
```

To be clear, the desired output would be:

```
  Country Ccode  Year Profit Scale    ID Happiness_d Power_d  ID_d
  <chr>   <fcr> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 France  FR     2000      1000  NA        1      40000. 160000.  1.67
2 France  FR     2001     -1200   1        1      80000. 320000.  1.67
3 France  FR     2000      1400   0        2      40000. 160000.  1.67
4 France  FR     2001      1600   3        2      80000. 320000.  1.67
5 UK      UK     2000     -1000  **NA**    3      40000. 160000.  1.67
6 UK      UK     2001      1000   2        3      80000. 320000.  1.67
7 UK      UK     2000      1000   4        4      40000. 160000.  1.67
8 UK      UK     2001      1000   0        4      80000. 320000.  1.67
```

dput example (please note that the varable `Scale` does not actually exist:

```
h7a = structure(c(1, -9, 2, 3, 1, 3, -9, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 
    3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, -9, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 
    3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, NA, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
    4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 
    3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, -9, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, -9, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 
    -9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
    3, 3, 1, -9, 1, -7, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, -7, 2, 3, 1, 3, -7, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 3, NA, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, -9, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    1, -9, -9, -9, 2, -9, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, -9, 4, 
    3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 
    -9, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, -7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, -7, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, NA, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, -9, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, NA, 1, 3, 3, -7, 1, 
    1, 3, 2, 1, 4), label = "The Court System Is Fair, Impartial And Uncorrupted", format.stata = "%24.0g", class = "labelled", labels = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, 1, 2, 3, 4), .Names = c("Don't Know (Spontaneous)", "Does Not Apply", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Tend to disagree", "Tend to agree", 
    "Strongly agree"))),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example that you can apply to your dataset.

```
# example data
df = data.frame(a = c("A","A","B"),
                x = c(1,2,3),
                y = c(NA,3,-7),
                z = c(200,300,-400))

library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ifelse(between(min(., na.rm = T), -9, -1) & .<0, NA, .))

#   a x  y    z
# 1 A 1 NA  200
# 2 A 2  3  300
# 3 B 3 NA -400
```

You can update (`mutate`) a column only if that column is numeric and the minimum value of that column is between -9 and -1. And the update is to replace negative values with `NA`.

This assumes you have only integer values. If not you can use `between(..., -9, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer AntoniosK. I have just figured out that I can get the factor values out by using `get_values()` (see my edit). Do you see any way to incorporate this into your solution. Maybe something like, `mutate_if(get_values() < 0)` ?

Comment: The edit is that you want to remove the negative factor values, but column `Scale` is not a factor variable.

Comment: I think I messed up somewhere in the example; the `Scale` variable actually has the same structure as the structure of the example variable in the post. My apologies for the confusion. I wanted to prevent confusion by not using `labelled` as a class, but I think I just made it more confusing.

Comment: Maybe you can use `dput()` so we can use data that replicate exactly the format and types of your columns.

Comment: I have rewritten the post and provided dput, I think it should be much clearer now.

Comment: So, what is the problem when you run my code on your real data? It breaks? It doesn't work correctly? It changes the column type?

Comment: Well, I cannot be certain that it works correctly. And there is no way to check because the dataset is so large. If I understand correctly, it is perfectly possible that there will be entries replaced with NA, which do not represent NA's, but are simply negative within the range -9 to -1, or am I misinterpreting your answer?

Comment: Yes, unless you know in advance the columns names you want to apply this logic, so you don't touch any other columns. And the question is, is there any way / logic we can apply to get the names of the columns you want to change?

Comment: Well I thought that this is where the `get_values()` could come in.. For the columns which should not be touched, I figured out that `get_values()` returns `NULL`. For other columns it returns the values. That is why I was wondering if we could include something like `mutate_if(get_values(df$var)=NULL& .<0, NA, .))`

Comment: Maybe you can use `df %>% select_if(~class(.) == "labbeled") %>% names()` to get the names of the variables you want to consider. Seems that the variables you want to update are of "labbeled" class/type.  And then use those column names inside `mutate_at`. If this looks reasonable please post a `dput` of the first 10 rows of your dataset so I can help you apply it.

Comment: Darn it.. I thought that was not the case, but on second instance I think you are actually right. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to try it yourself. If you can't make it work I'll be able to help you, but I'll need some data from you so I can have some "labelled" variables as well.

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble with the dplyr syntax. I thought I could perhaps try `df %>% mutate_if(~class(.) == "labelled"), ~ifelse(between(min(., na.rm = T), -9, -1) & .<0, NA, .))` but that gives a syntax error: `Error: unexpected `','` in "df<- df%>% mutate_if(~class(.) == "labelled"),"

Comment: Verified! Wow.. That is a good start of the weekend. Thank you so much for your patience, I realize I have not been all that clear..

Answer (score 0):

Base-R Solution:

```
# Find negative value from 3rd column onwards, replace it with NA 
# and bind with Country,Ccode and Profit columns. 
cbind(df[,c(1,2,4)],do.call(cbind, lapply(df[,-c(1,2,4)], function(x) ifelse(x<0,NA,x))))
```

Output:

```
     Country Ccode Profit Year Scale ID Happiness_d Power_d ID_d
  1  France    FR   1000 2000    NA  1       40000  160000 1.67
  2  France    FR  -1200 2001     1  1       80000  320000 1.67
  3  France    FR   1400 2000     0  2       40000  160000 1.67
  4  France    FR   1600 2001     3  2       80000  320000 1.67
  5      UK    UK  -1000 2000    NA  3       40000  160000 1.67
  6      UK    UK   1000 2001     2  3       80000  320000 1.67
  7      UK    UK   1000 2000     4  4       40000  160000 1.67
  8      UK    UK   1000 2001     0  4       80000  320000 1.67
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you misunderstood my question. The idea was to prevent certain columns such as `Profit` from being affected. As an additional note,  I have noticed that I can use `get_values(df)` to get out the factor levels. Would it be possible to incorporate that in your answer, i.e. to apply your solution only to the factor levels?

Comment: @TomKisters: I can help to exclude `Profit` from it.

Comment: Would it be possible to do that using the information from get_values() ? Please see my edit.